# Socket.IO Spring server, Cant Connect with browser, only with Node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spring, socket.io

Hey I have the following Spring Boot Application, that have a SocketIoServer Endpoint on top of it, the server worked completly fine while testing in a client written in Node.js enviroment, but on a browser (Chrome and Edge, haven't tested different ones) There is no response from the server.

I am using the following Socket.IO-Server Library: https://github.com/trinopoty/socket.io-server-java
and followed the guide for connecting to Spring Boot Application which be found here: https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-server-java/blob/master/docs/spring-integration.rst

**ServerApplication.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {

    @Bean
    public EngineIoServer engineIoServer(){
        EngineIoServerOptions options = EngineIoServerOptions.newFromDefault();
        options.setAllowedCorsOrigins(new String[]{"*"});
        options.setPingTimeout(30000);
        EngineIoServer engineIoServer = new EngineIoServer(options);
        SocketIoServer socketIoServer = new SocketIoServer(engineIoServer);
        socketIoServer.namespace("/game").on("connection", args -> {
            System.out.println("Connected");
        });
        return engineIoServer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class,args);
    }
}
```

**EngineIoConfigurator.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class EngineIoConfigurator implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private final EngineIoHandler mEngineIoHandler;

    public EngineIoConfigurator(EngineIoHandler engineIoHandler){
        mEngineIoHandler = engineIoHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry){
      registry.addHandler(mEngineIoHandler,"/socket.io/").addInterceptors(mEngineIoHandler);
      registry.addHandler(mEngineIoHandler,"/engine.io/").addInterceptors(mEngineIoHandler);
    }

}
```

**EngineIoHandler.java**

```java
@Controller
public class EngineIoHandler implements HandshakeInterceptor, WebSocketHandler {

    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_ENGINEIO_BRIDGE = "engineIo.bridge";
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_ENGINEIO_QUERY = "engineIo.query";

    private final EngineIoServer mEngineIoServer;

    public EngineIoHandler(EngineIoServer engineIoServer) {
        mEngineIoServer = engineIoServer;
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/engine.io/*",
            method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.OPTIONS},
            headers = "Connection!=Upgrade")
    public void httpHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        mEngineIoServer.handleRequest(request,response);
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/socket.io/*",
            method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.OPTIONS},
            headers = "Connection!=Upgrade")
    public void httpHandler2(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        mEngineIoServer.handleRequest(request,response);
    }

    /* HandshakeInterceptor */

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws IOException {
        attributes.put(ATTRIBUTE_ENGINEIO_QUERY,request.getURI().getQuery());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {

    }

    /* WebSocketHandler */

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
        final EngineIoSpringWebSocket websocket = new EngineIoSpringWebSocket(webSocketSession);
        webSocketSession.getAttributes().put(ATTRIBUTE_ENGINEIO_BRIDGE, websocket);
        mEngineIoServer.handleWebSocket(websocket);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession webSocketSession, CloseStatus closeStatus) {
        ((EngineIoSpringWebSocket)webSocketSession.getAttributes().get(ATTRIBUTE_ENGINEIO_BRIDGE))
                .afterConnectionClosed(closeStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession webSocketSession, WebSocketMessage<?> webSocketMessage) {
        ((EngineIoSpringWebSocket)webSocketSession.getAttributes().get(ATTRIBUTE_ENGINEIO_BRIDGE))
                .handleMessage(webSocketMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession webSocketSession, Throwable throwable) {
        ((EngineIoSpringWebSocket)webSocketSession.getAttributes().get(ATTRIBUTE_ENGINEIO_BRIDGE))
                .handleTransportError(throwable);
    }

    private static final class EngineIoSpringWebSocket extends EngineIoWebSocket {

        private final WebSocketSession mSession;
        private final Map<String, String> mQuery;

        EngineIoSpringWebSocket(WebSocketSession session) {
            mSession = session;

            final String queryString = (String)mSession.getAttributes().get(ATTRIBUTE_ENGINEIO_QUERY);
            if (queryString != null) {
                mQuery = ParseQS.decode(queryString);
            } else {
                mQuery = new HashMap<>();
            }
        }

        /* EngineIoWebSocket */

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getQuery() {
            return mQuery;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, List<String>> getConnectionHeaders() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(String message) throws IOException {
            mSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage(message));
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] message) throws IOException {
            mSession.sendMessage(new BinaryMessage(message));
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            try {
                mSession.close();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            }
        }

        /* WebSocketHandler */

        void afterConnectionClosed(CloseStatus closeStatus) {
            emit("close");
        }

        void handleMessage(WebSocketMessage<?> message) {
            if (message.getPayload() instanceof String || message.getPayload() instanceof byte[]) {
                emit("message", (Object) message.getPayload());
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format(
                        "Invalid message type received: %s. Expected String or byte[].",
                        message.getPayload().getClass().getName()));
            }
        }

        void handleTransportError(Throwable exception) {
            emit("error", "write error", exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the client code written in Node.js, which is working as intendent.

**main.js**

```js
const io = require('socket.io-client');

socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4919/game', {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    reconnection: false
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected');    
});
```

but the browser application, have the same code but not working

**index.html**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-fKnu0iswBIqkjxrhQCTZ7qlLHOFEgNkRmK2vaO/LbTZSXdJfAu6ewRBdwHPhBo/H" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io('http://localhost:4919/game', {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        reconnection: false
    });

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
    });
</script>
```

The browsers gives the following error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4919/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:
```

and In the network panel I can see no connection was established.

[image]

Just for testing purposes I put up a node.js socket.io server to see that the browser connected the server succsfully and I got the following response.

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I found out that by changing the transports to polling make the connection stable, but I still want it to be websocket if possible.

```js
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-fKnu0iswBIqkjxrhQCTZ7qlLHOFEgNkRmK2vaO/LbTZSXdJfAu6ewRBdwHPhBo/H" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io('http://localhost:4919/game', {
        transports: ['polling'],
        reconnection: false
    });

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
    });
</script>
```

which yield the following result.
[image]

I still haven't found a way to use the websocket transport.

Comment: what is your spring boot version?

Comment: Oh sorry, I found the answer but forgot I posted on here, I willl upload my findings.

Answer (score 1):

maybe not answer of this question directly but i spend many hours on getting message that emit from javascript client.

problem was you need to use same version with javascript and java

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
        <artifactId>socket.io-server</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "shortid": "^2.2.14",
    "simple-peer": "^9.5.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1"
  }
```

Comment: I couldn't find any example of socket.io-server dependency with spring boot. There are only examples of com.corundumstudio.socketio. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer is related to cors. my fix was to add cors.

**EngineIoConfigurator.java**

```java
registry.addHandler(mEngineIoHandler,"/socket.io/*").addInterceptors(mEngineIoHandler).setAllowedOrigins("*");
registry.addHandler(mEngineIoHandler,"/engine.io/*").addInterceptors(mEngineIoHandler).setAllowedOrigins("*");
```